# Equivalent in wood/coal/methane of one litre of petrol

Tags: energy, physical-chemistry, estimation, chemical-compounds

I want to create a visual comparison between different sources of energy. I would like to show how much wood, coal, methane, water+level difference, etc. could potentially generate the same energy of one litre of petrol.
I would I go about it with some calculations? And are there some data I can use as a reference?

Comment: Heats of combustion per kg generally work pretty well for this purpose.

Comment: [This link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_of_combustion#Heat_of_combustion_tables) has a table with heats of combustion.

Comment: Would [chemistry.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: -1. No research effort. Did you try using an internet search to find data?

Answer (score 4):

The best ever IMO is [this link](http://energyeducation.ca/encyclopedia/Energy_density)
which contains data as well as this nice [image]

pictorial answer from xkcd (link to original comic [here](https://xkcd.com/1162/)).